# Unexpected outputs of logging.config.fileConfig in logging package of Python

Tags: python, logging

I'm planning to extract logging configurations from code into `logging.conf` file.
But the behavior seems to differ from one another.

Current simple hard coded case is:

```
import sys
import logging
import logging.handlers

# loggers
root = logging.getLogger()
mylogger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")

# handler
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)

# formatter
simpleFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

# config
consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
consoleHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter)
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root.addHandler(consoleHandler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylogger.debug("mylogger debug")
    mylogger.info("mylogger info")
    mylogger.warning("mylogger warning")
    mylogger.error("mylogger error")

    root.debug("root debug")
    root.info("root info")
    root.warning("root warning")
    root.error("root error")
```

And the (presumably) comparable configuration using `logging.conf` is:

```
import logging
import logging.config

# loggers
root = logging.getLogger()
mylogger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load configuration from a file
    logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")

    mylogger.debug("mylogger debug")
    mylogger.info("mylogger info")
    mylogger.warning("mylogger warning")
    mylogger.error("mylogger error")

    root.debug("root debug")
    root.info("root info")
    root.warning("root warning")
    root.error("root error")
```

`logging.conf` is:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter


[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
args=(sys.stderr,)
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

The output of former includes logs from `mylogger`:

```
2013-10-19 21:36:05,866 - mylogger - INFO - mylogger info
2013-10-19 21:36:05,866 - mylogger - WARNING - mylogger warning
2013-10-19 21:36:05,866 - mylogger - ERROR - mylogger error
2013-10-19 21:36:05,866 - root - INFO - root info
2013-10-19 21:36:05,866 - root - WARNING - root warning
2013-10-19 21:36:05,866 - root - ERROR - root error
```

, but the one of latter does NOT includes logs from `mylogger`:

```
2013-10-19 21:38:39,753 - root - INFO - root info
2013-10-19 21:38:39,753 - root - WARNING - root warning
2013-10-19 21:38:39,753 - root - ERROR - root error
```

In my real project, logger objects appear in many files with `logger = logging.getLogger (__name__)`, so it is hard to list all loggers in `logging.conf` except the 'root' logger.

Is there a good way to fix the latter example in order to get the same output of the former case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.6 or later, you should call `logging.config.fileConfig()` with an additional keyword argument, `disable_existing_loggers=False` (the default is `True` to preserve backward compatibility, but there's no other reason to use that default).

Without `disable_existing_loggers=False`, any existing loggers when `fileConfig()` is called are disabled unless they or an ancestor of theirs is named in the configuration.

Comment: Exactly! I missed the Warning section of the ["Logging HOWTO"](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) document. Thanks a lot!